# FindDialog lazarus/delphi

Tags: delphi, lazarus

Здравствуйте!
Я бы хотел сделать поиск, чтобы было такое:У меня 10 форм, в каждой форме расположены кнопки. В 1 форме(главном меню) есть кнопка "поиск", когда поиск открывается я ввожу "масса тела" которая расположена в 9 форме и он телепортирует туда.
А можно сделать так: в каждой форме создать memo(они будут скрыты) там написать все кнопки и помощью поиска он находил эти метки и телепортировал к форме где эти метки расположены.
Мне надо код или как-то мне помочь по 1 способу или по 2.

Comment: @hepro, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы описал интерфейс или класс TFinder который принимает SearchPattern в виде строки, и возвращает список объектов, которые подпадает под условие SearchPattern. Объектами являются формы, которовые при создании(OnCreate) регистрируются в классе: GlobalFinder.RegisterForm(Self) а в уничтожении(OnDestroy) отменяют регистрацию GlobalFinder.UnregisterForm(Self).

У каждой регистрируемой формы должны быть методы/свойства о которых знает TFinder и ищет по ним во всех зарег. объектах.